# How to swap the position of a jquery ui tab with another ui tab using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

If I create a jQuery UI tab control. I add one tab. I add a second tab. How do I switch the position of the tab?

I want to be able to create a new tab at the start of the tab buttons, so I use

```
$('.tabs').tabs("add","tabContent.htm","New Tab")
```

but this creates the tab and appends it to the end of the exisiting tab buttons, but I need it to appear at the start. How can I switch their positions using jquery?

Unsure how to remove and re-add the button before the other ones.

Comment: Looks like you got an answer.  You can also let your users order the tabs with: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/sortable.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.tabs').tabs("add","tabContent.htm","New Tab", 0)
```

Comment: adding 0 at the end makes that tab selected.  He wants it to be prepended to the tabs container to appear as the first tab.

Comment: sorry, my bad, yes, comma should be there 100%

Comment: Oh, it looks like you already marked this one as the answer, but since mine was already upvoted I went ahead and added it to my answer for anyone who stumbles across this in a search of a similar question.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that there is an optional 4th parameter for the .tabs method which allows for this.

```
.tabs( "add" , url , label , [index] );
```

I think this would work.

```
$('.tabs').tabs("add","tabContent.htm","New Tab", 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quiet sure the syntax of .tabs() but it sounds like you want .prepend().  Something like this:

```
//assuming .tabs is the tab container
$('.tabs').prepend( $(this).tabs("add","tabContent.htm","New Tab") );
```